# Change the color of Bootstrap navbar and reduce the height of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a landing page in bootstrap so i have added the fixed navbar in which i had login form in right side the login form is adding more height to the navbar actually i used position to move to top but the height of the navbar is not reducing (i also tried margin-top and padding-top)and also i want to change the color of navbar (i tried to change the color of navbar by using background-color and !important property )how do i solve this problem

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyLandingPage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.mlcdn.co/animate.css">
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand.navbar-header{
  font-size:30px;
  color:black;
}
.navbar{
  background-color: #5b4282;
}
#bodycontainer{
  background-image:url(wood.jpg);
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
}
form{
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
}
#myheader h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:250px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;

}
#txt1{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt2{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt3{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt4{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.mybutton{
  margin-left:250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-brand navbar-header">
        My@PP
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-example">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="myform">
          <input type="email" placeholder="username@abc.com" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="*********" class="form-control"/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Log-In</button>
          </form>

      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="bodycontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="myheader">
        <h1 class="animated ZoomIn infinite ">MY APPLICATION</h1>
        <p class="lead" id="txt1">This Why You Should Download The App</p>
        <p id="txt2">For more Information about the app please scroll down the more to access the information you can get the idea about it</p>
        <p id="txt3">If u are intrested please join our maling list</p>
        <br/>  <br/>  <br/>
        <form class="">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
        </form>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mybutton">Submit</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 id="txt4">Why this app is Osome...?</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
$("#bodycontainer").css("height",$(window).height());
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give us a fiddle or plunker of your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to override the default css values coming from the bootstrap by your css values.

Here class navbar is controlling the minimum height and color background color of the navigation bar , So changing their css properties can solve your problem.

I have done this one :

> **.navbar{   background: red;   max-height: 50px; }**

Place the above css in your page , and it will work as you want .you can change the values as your demand.